# Django and Ajax Push Engine (APE): Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: javascript, python, django, ape

I am trying to setup an APE server for my Django project.

### Setup

1. I followed the setup instructions in the APE wiki: [Simple APE Configuration](http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Simple_APE_configuration)

   I had to change the port though. My virtual host config reads as follows:

   ```
   NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8100
   Listen 127.0.0.1:8100
   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8100>
       ServerName local.ape-project.org
       ServerAlias ape.local.ape-project.org
       ServerAlias *.ape.local.ape-project.org

       DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/project/ape-jsf/"
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   Running http://local.ape-project.org:8100/Tools/Check/ runs all tests successfully and returns the message: `All test done. Now you can play with your APE \o/`
2. Django is running on port 8000:

   `python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000`
3. I followed the instructions for the first tutorial: [Tutorial: Color Changer](http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorial%3aColor_changer)

   I put the JavaScript code into my django project (with inclusion of `Clients/JavaScript.js`).

### Problem

When i open the page, i get this error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://2.ape.local.ape-project.org:6969/?[{%22cmd%22:%22script%22,%22params%22:{%22domain%22:%22127.0.0.1%22,%22scripts%22:[%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/mootools-core.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Core/APE.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Core/Events.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Core/Core.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Pipe/Pipe.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Pipe/PipeProxy.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Pipe/PipeMulti.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Pipe/PipeSingle.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Request/Request.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Request/Request.Stack.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Request/Request.CycledStack.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Transport/Transport.longPolling.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Transport/Transport.SSE.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Transport/Transport.XHRStreaming.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Transport/Transport.JSONP.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Core/Utility.js%22,%22http://local.ape-project.org:8100/static/ape-jsf/Source/Core/JSON.js%22]}}]
from frame with URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/mydjangoapp/somepage/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I understand that there is a security issue with different domains and ports.

**But how is this supposed to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that it's difficult to configure an environment that runs both `Ape` and `runserver`. The solution to this problem is to use another web server.

I chose Apache and the mod_wsgi module:

- mod_wsgi tutorial: [Integration With Django](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango)
- be careful about static files: [How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I have dev.mydomain.com and ape.mydomain.com. Is this how you are setup, or are you running everything from the same domain? Thanks.

Comment: I found an answer from their google groups. By adding {transport:2} as a parameter to client.load() like client.load({transport: 2}); it works with different subdomains https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/ape-project/Domains,$20protocols$20and$20ports$20must$20match./ape-project/hOwoKSDLsug/NUXkM7MTgPEJ

Comment: By the way, i dumped APE because there are better alternatives. Currently, i am very happy with sockjs. See this excellent answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10950702/675065

Comment: I will check it out and see how it goes. I do not need the same volume of messages, but possibly many connections. I need something to avoid interval polling for 1 or 2 messages every 10 minutes for many users. I'll run some tests on APE and if that does not work switch to sockjs. Thanks.